# Getting those error message while I am doing Full CIL

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Getting those error message while I am doing Full CIL.

```
Finished pass 1 at 1/29/2020 1:56:55 PM

Finished pass 2 at 1/29/2020 1:57:02 PM

Could not find CustVendTransExchAdjDistController_RU.ledgerDimensionObtained in the method map. Will attempt to use X++ delegates.

Could not find AccountingDistributionView.initializedControls in the method map. Will attempt to use X++ delegates.

Finished pass 3 at 1/29/2020 1:57:15 PM
Finished creating types at 1/29/2020 1:57:16 PM
Errors: 0
Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like your environment is not fully compiled before you performed the full CIL. You compile AX (p-code) then compile that into CIL.

Just perform a full AX compile then do your CIL. The last link is a short-cut to solve the specific objects, but if you have a few objects with issue, you likely have more, so do a full one.

See:

- AXBuild: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/axbuild-exe-for-parallel-compile-on-aos-of-x-to-p-code
- Example of AXBuild: https://www.tech.alirazazaidi.com/using-axbuild-for-fast-compilation-in-dynamics-ax-2012-r3/
- Error reference: https://www.mylesyamada.com/?p=207